# knife.timer on Lua syntax - not behaving as expected

Tags: timer, lua, love2d

If anyone is familiar with knife.timer on Lua, could you please look at my code and tell me what I have out of order?

I'm hoping to do two things:

1. have a countdown timer that ticks down every second and
2. have a timer that after six seconds begins blinking my characters for 3 more seconds before changing state.

With the following code, my countdown timer starts at 9 but gets well into the negative tens. My characters begin to blink after what feels like 4 seconds, and continue blinking for a few seconds after changing state.

I have `Timer:update(dt)` in main, so I'm not sure why the timing is off. And I thought the finish would not call the change state function until the characters' 16 iterations of blinking were done.

```lua
function PlayerPilotState:update(dt)
    self.player.currentAnimation:update(dt)
    Timer.every(1, function()
        self.timer = self.timer - 1
    end)
    
    Timer.after(6, function()
        Timer.every(0.2, function() 
            self.player.blinking = not self.player.blinking
            self.player.otherPlayer.blinking = not self.player.otherPlayer.blinking
        end):finish(function()
            self.player:changeState('falling')
            self.player.otherPlayer:changeState('falling')
        end):limit(16)
    end)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used knife.timer, but it seems like this code is in an update function that happens for every frame of your game.  Are you sure it's not creating lots of timers?

Answer (score 1):

1. With the basic countdown timer, you never specify when it should stop. Try using `:limit(9)` or `self.timer = math.max(0,self.timer - 1)`

2.Have you timed it properly (it's hard to *feel* how much time has passed), since you use Timer.after. The `:finish()` function happens inside the `:after()`, and after the `:every()`, which could cause things to be weird. I suggest adding the `:limit` before the `:finish()`.

```
Timer.after(6, function()
        Timer.every(0.2, function() 
            self.player.blinking = not self.player.blinking
            self.player.otherPlayer.blinking = not self.player.otherPlayer.blinking
        end):limit(16):finish(function()
            self.player:changeState('falling')
            self.player.otherPlayer:changeState('falling')
        end)
    end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above comments were extremely useful.  It turns out that putting timers under update is a bad idea because they either are calling new timers or refreshing strangely.  What I ended up with, and works perfectly is:

```
function PlayerPilotState:enter(params)
    Timer.every(1, function()
        self.timer = self.timer - 1
    end)

    Timer.after(6, function()
        Timer.every(0.2, function() 
            self.player.blinking = not self.player.blinking
            self.player.otherPlayer.blinking = not self.player.otherPlayer.blinking
        end)
        :limit(15)
        :finish(function()
            self.player.blinking = false
            self.player.otherPlayer.blinking = false 
            self.player:changeState('falling')
            self.player.otherPlayer:changeState('falling')
        end)
    end)

end
```

A follow up question I would have, is how to do this without using an enter function?  I guess any function call that called only once (with maybe a boolean flag to call it) would work.  Thanks!